# Sorting lines based on column

Tags: java, sorting

Is there any way where we can sort based on columns?

I have lines like,

```
1000 Australia     Kangaroo            Canberra
1002 India         Tiger               Delhi
1092 Germany       Eagle               Berlin
```

The above lines has to be sorted based on the second column, that is Australia, Germany, India.

So, the result should be,

```
1000 Australia     Kangaroo            Canberra
1092 Germany       Eagle               Berlin   
1002 India         Tiger               Delhi
```

Data is from text file

Comment: are they object of an List or table record? when you are writing or logging your data you can use bubble sort algorithm to sort

Comment: It would be trivial to offer the user the ability to do that, using a `JTable`.  Though I guess that is not the functionality you are trying to implement.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `TreeSet` and reading your text file and keeping your data in a class that implements `Comparable`. That way, when you're adding to the `TreeSet` the data would get added in a sorted order.

This example might help:

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data>{

    private int digits;
    private String country;
    private String animal;
    private String capital;

    public Data(int digits, String country, String animal, String capital){
        this.digits = digits;
        this.country = country;
        this.animal = animal;
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public int getDigits() {
        return digits;
    }

    public void setDigits(int digits) {
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }

    public void setCapital(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data data) {
        return getCountry().compareTo(data.getCountry());
    }
}


class TestCountry{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Data> set = new TreeSet<Data>();
        /** 
         * Assuming that you can read the CSV file and build up the Data objects.
         * You would then put them in the set where they will be added in a sorted
         * fashion 
         */
        set.add(new Data(1000, "Australia", "Kangaroo", "Canberra"));
        set.add(new Data(1002, "India", "Tiger", "Delhi"));
        set.add(new Data(1092, "Germany", "Eagle", "Berlin"));

        for(Data data: set){
            System.out.println(data.getDigits()+"\t"+data.getCountry()+"\t"+data.getAnimal()+"\t"+data.getCapital());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can struct your data as this model

**Row Class** represent row data

```
public class Row implements Comparable<Row> {

private int number;
private String country;
private String animal;
private String city;

public Row(int number, String country, String animal, String city) {
    super();
    this.number = number;
    this.country = country;
    this.animal = animal;
    this.city = city;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}

public void setAnimal(String animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

// Easy to print and show the row data
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Row [number=" + number + ", country=" + country + ", animal="
            + animal + ", city=" + city + "]";
}

// sort based on column "country"
@Override
public int compareTo(Row o) {
    return this.country.compareTo(o.country);
}
```

}

and the test **example** will be as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Row> data = new ArrayList<Row>();
    data.add(new Row(1000, "Australia", "Kangaroo", "Canberra"));
    data.add(new Row(1002, "India", "Tiger", "Delhi"));
    data.add(new Row(1092, "Germany", "Eagle", "Berlin"));

    // To sort the data (based on column "country")
    Collections.sort(data);

    // Print and show the data
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(data.get(i));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read that file line by line and use a StringTokenizer on each line to have access to the single words. You can then put each line into a HashMap with the country as key.

Using

```
Collection<String> k = yourHashMap.keySet();
Collections.sort(k);
```

Would sort your key set in natural order. You can then iterate over the key set and access each line in the hashmap in a sorted way.

Comment: Ok, then i would suggest you read that file line by line and use a StringTokenizer on each line to have access to the single words. You can then put this structure into a collection with the country at the very beginning and call Collection.sort(yourCollection); which will sort the collection in natuaral order

Comment: @Markus: Edit your answer and make this as part of your answer. The way your answer stands, it looks more like a `comment` rather than a real `answer` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer on how this could be done with streams and a `Comparator`.

- The sort method takes a comparator.
- the comparator takes a key extractor, in this case the second column after spliting the string.
- then using that key, the sort is done on a case insensitive fashion in natural order (ascending for strings).

```
String[] data = { 
        "000 Australia     Kangaroo            Canberra",
        "002 India         Tiger               Delhi",
        "092 Germany       Eagle               Berlin" };

String[] result = Arrays.stream(data)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[1],
                String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

for (String lines : result) {
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

prints

```
000 Australia     Kangaroo            Canberra
092 Germany       Eagle               Berlin
002 India         Tiger               Delhi
```

**Note:**

For case dependent comparisons, either of the following would work.

`Comparator.naturalOrder()` and `Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())))`